Using the same Facebook App for different features requiring different permissions
We're providing a large SaaS CRM-like system.
One of the features in our CRM allows customers to collect leads directly from FB Lead Ads forms. For this propose we have fb app reviewed and approved with all permissions necessary to retrieve leads.
Now we plan to develop a new feature that isn't related to leads retrieval.
This new feature has a few common fb permissions with lead-ads, but also requires a few additional permissions relevant for the new functionality only.
We doubt either we need to create a new dedicated FB APP for this new feature with its own set of permissions, or continue using the existing app and just request for additional permissions.
On one hand Facebook allows using the same app for different features, so continuing using the existing app looks like a good choice.
On the other hand Facebook Annual Data Use checkup requires to provide detailed instructions and step-by-step guide for how a customer can login and use all granted permissions in our CRM.
We have concerns that explaining different features with different activation walkthrough within the same App Data Usage Check may be too complex and cumbersome....
Please advice
